# lodash Filter collection using array of values

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I would like to filter a collection using array of property value. Given an array of IDs, return objects with matching IDs. Is there any shortcut method using `lodash`/`underscore`?

```js
var collections = [{ id: 1, name: 'xyz' },
                   { id: 2,  name: 'ds' },
                   { id: 3,  name: 'rtrt' },
                   { id: 4,  name: 'nhf' },
                   { id: 5,  name: 'qwe' }];
var ids = [1,3,4];

// This works, but any better way?

var filtered = _.select(collections, function(c){    
    return ids.indexOf(c.id) != -1
});
```

Comment: Not really. But you could deal directly with the `filter()` method of Arrays prototypes; looks cleaner :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you're going to use this sort of pattern a lot, you could create a mixin like the following, though, it isn't doing anything fundementally different than your original code. It just makes it more developer friendly.

```
_.mixin({
  'findByValues': function(collection, property, values) {
    return _.filter(collection, function(item) {
      return _.contains(values, item[property]);
    });
  }
});
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
var collections = [
    {id: 1, name: 'xyz'}, 
    {id: 2,  name: 'ds'},
    {id: 3,  name: 'rtrt'},
    {id: 4,  name: 'nhf'},
    {id: 5,  name: 'qwe'}
];

var filtered = _.findByValues(collections, "id", [1,3,4]);
```

**Update** - This above answer is old and clunky. Please use the [answer from Adam Boduch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878221/5651) for a much more elegant solution.

```
_(collections)
  .keyBy('id') // or .indexBy() if using lodash 3.x
  .at(ids)
  .value();
```

Comment: you're missing the end  quote on keyBy. I would correct but SO won't let me add a single character  ;)

Answer (score 48):

A concise lodash solution that uses [indexBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) and [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at).

```
// loDash 4
_.chain(collections)
 .keyBy('id')
 .at(ids)
 .value();

// below loDash 4
_(collections)
 .indexBy('id')
 .at(ids)
 .value();
```

Comment: This pithiness of this solution is splendid. And Lodash 4 users can simply replace `indexBy` with `keyBy` for this to continue functioning.

Comment: If `collections` doesn't contain any objects that match up with `ids`, it seems to return an array with one element of undefined. `[undefined`]. This fails my go test of `someArray.length` so I added a `.filter()`

`_(collections).keyBy('id').at(ids).filter().value();`

Answer (score 19):

We can also filter like this

```
var collections = [{ id: 1, name: 'xyz' },
            { id: 2,  name: 'ds' },
            { id: 3,  name: 'rtrt' },
            { id: 4,  name: 'nhf' },
            { id: 5,  name: 'qwe' }];



        var filtered_ids = _.filter(collections, function(p){
            return _.includes([1,3,4], p.id);
        });

        console.log(filtered_ids);
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked great for me:

```
let output = _.filter(collections, (v) => _.includes(ids, v.id));
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for me too, yet, I have used `reject` to simplfiy filter  
`let output = _.reject(collections, v => _.includes(ids, v.id));
`

Comment: @edencorbin How can it be achieved if the ids are also a list of objects with both id and name properties

Comment: There may be a less code approach but I would reduce that to just the ids, something like const ids = arrayofobjects.map(x=>x.id)

Answer (score 7):

I like [jessegavin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18830961/441662) answer, but I expanded on it using [lodash-deep](https://github.com/marklagendijk/lodash-deep) for deep property matching.

```js
var posts = [{ term: { name: 'A', process: '123A' } }, 
             { term: { name: 'B', process: '123B' } }, 
             { term: { name: 'C', process: '123C' } }];

var result = _.filterByValues(posts, 'term.process', ['123A', '123C']);
// results in objects A and C to be returned
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/rw6jdkpg/)

```js
_.mixin({
    'filterByValues': function(collection, key, values) {
        return _.filter(collection, function(o) {
            return _.contains(values, resolveKey(o, key));
        });
    }
});

function resolveKey(obj, key) {
    return (typeof key == 'function') ? key(obj) : _.deepGet(obj, key);
}
```

If you don't trust lodash-deep or you want support for properties that have dots in their names, here's a more defensive and robust version:

```js
function resolveKey(obj, key) {
    if (obj == null || key == null) {
        return undefined;
    }
    var resolved = undefined;
    if (typeof key == 'function') {
        resolved = key(obj);
    } else if (typeof key == 'string' ) {
        resolved = obj[key];
        if (resolved == null && key.indexOf(".") != -1) {
            resolved = _.deepGet(obj, key);
        }
    }
    return resolved;
}
```

Comment: lodash `get` is deep by default, so you can do things like `_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');`.
So all you have to do to make @jessegavin answer support deep properties is change `item[property]` with `_.get(item, property)`. See [lodash documents](https://lodash.com/docs#get).

Answer (score 3):

These answers didn't work for me, because I wanted to filter on a non-unique value. If you change `keyBy` to `groupBy` you can get by.

```
_(collections)
  .groupBy(attribute)
  .pick(possibleValues)
  .values()
  .flatten()
  .value();
```

My initial use was to drop things, so I switched out `pick` with `omit`.

Thanks [Adam Boduch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878221/1921234) for the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed many of these answers are outdated or contain auxiliary functions not listed in Lodash documentation. The accepted answer includes deprecated function `_.contains` and should be updated.

So here is my ES6 answer.

Based on [Lodash v4.17.4](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)

```
_.mixin( {
    filterByValues: ( c, k, v ) => _.filter(
        c, o => _.indexOf( v, o[ k ] ) !== -1
    )
} );
```

And invoked as such:

```
_.filterByValues(
    [
        {
            name: 'StackOverflow'
        },
        {
            name: 'ServerFault'
        },
        {
            name: 'AskDifferent'
        }
    ],
    'name',
    [ 'StackOverflow', 'ServerFault' ]
);

// => [ { name: 'StackOverflow' }, { name: 'ServerFault' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to join the party late, but nowadays the clearest way to do it would be by using **_.reject**

```
_.reject(collections, ({id}) => _.includes(ids, id));
```

Basically, we are rejecting all the values that meet a specific criteria, in this case that the ID is included in the `ids` array.