# How to filter the array of objects

Tags: arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have array of objects like this

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true , 'company':'abc' },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false, 'company':'pqr' },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true,  'company':'xyz' }
];
```

i want filter the array of objects where **company is abc or xyz** so the result should be like this

```
[
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true , 'company':'abc' },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true,  'company':'xyz' }
];
```

i am using the loadash like this

```
console.log(_.filter(users, {'company': 'xyz','company': 'abc'}))
```

It is not filtering correctly. can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lodash Filter collection using array of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251764/lodash-filter-collection-using-array-of-values)

Comment: hi, did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the default syntax, this should work

```
  _.filter(users, function(user) { return user.company == 'abc' || user.company == 'xyz'; });
```

The short reason that your code didn't work in the first place

`_.filter(users, {'company': 'xyz','company': 'abc'})`

is because you were passing a javascript object with duplicated property name `company` hence the second property with value `abc` overrides the first property. Which means you were actually doing this

`_.filter(users, {'company': 'abc'})`

This object `{'company': 'abc'}` will then be passed to `_.matches` to produce a function, this function will then validate each element of the array.

```
  var predicate = _.matches({'company': 'abc'});
  predicate( { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true , 'company':'abc' }); // true
  predicate(  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false, 'company':'pqr' }); // false
  predicate(    { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true,  'company':'xyz' }); // false
```

which results in only barney is returned.