# Get items from collection by array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, filter, lodash

I wonder what is best and easiest way to get elements by array element from collection - is it possible by using native js?

Here is what is the case:

```
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const collection = [{id: 2}, {id: 234}, {id:1}, {id: 345}, {id: 3}, {id:4}, {id:323}];
```

Expected output should looks like that:

```
[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
```

Is there already something built in to lodash? I know we can use filter and indexOf but I wonder what is the shortest and easiest way to do this.

Comment: `array.filter` is enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lodash Filter collection using array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251764/lodash-filter-collection-using-array-of-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Simple JS*

Using `filter` with the combination of `includes`

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const collection = [{id: 2}, {id: 234}, {id:1}, {id: 345}, {id: 3}, {id:4}, {id:323}];

const found = collection.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id));

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you can use [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#keyBy) to index the `collection` by `id`, then get the items by the `ids` using [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#at):

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const collection = [{id: 2}, {id: 234}, {id:1}, {id: 345}, {id: 3}, {id:4}, {id:323}];

const result = _.at(_.keyBy(collection, 'id'), ids);
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the order of output has to be in sync with `id`s, use `map` and `find`

```
var output = ids.map( s => collection.find( t => t.id == s ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var collection = [{
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 234
}, {
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 345
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 323
}];
var output = ids.map(s => collection.find(t => t.id == s));
console.log(output);
```

In case there are some values in `ids` **which don't have an equivalent value in `collection`**, then use `filter` after `map`

```
var output = ids.map(s => collection.find(t => t.id == s)).filter( s => !!s );
```

**Demo**

```js
var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var collection = [{
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 234
}, {
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 345
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 323
}];
var output = ids.map(s => collection.find(t => t.id == s)).filter( s => s );
console.log(output);
```